# Solution For Customizing DataTable Search Field

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, datatables, placeholder, inputtext

I want to Customize Jquery DataTable Search text field
and put an icon inside the text field
The Jquery Datatable Provide Some Features To Customize its built-in Fields How to Resolve This
Help me Any One Please
Is there any other Solution Without Customizing ??
Is DataTable Providing Feature of TextField Customization With Icons??

here is my dataTable Code

```
 $('#FamilyMembersTable').DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        //"searchDelay": 10000,
        "destroy": true,
        "ScrollX": true,
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "ajax": {
            url: "/Home/GetFamilyMembers",
            data: function(data) {
                data.IsChildAccount = false;
                data.PatientId = $('#hdn_PatientIdForFamilyMemberInsertion').val();
            },
            type: 'POST',
        },
       columns": [
             {
                 "data": "DateOfBirth",
                 render: function (data) {
                     return moment(data).format('MMM DD, YYYY');
                 }

             },

             {
                 "data": "Gender"

             },
              {
                  "data": "Email",

              },
               
                },
        ],

        "columnDefs": [
            { "className": "text-left", "targets": [0,1,3, 5] },
            { "className": "text-center", "targets": [2,6] }
        ],
       
        },

        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": '<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm mr-2">' +
                '<option value="10">10</option>' +
                '<option value="25">25</option>' +
                '<option value="50">50</option>' +
                '<option value="100">100</option></select>Show on page',
            "search": ""

        }
        
    });
```